# Probability of groups occurring in the set of permutations

Tags: probability, statistics

I was given this question as homework:

At a European summit, four Germans, three Italians, and six Frenchmen are seated randomly
on the front row. Find the probability that all members from the same country will be seated
together.

Here is what I did so far:

Germans: $4$ members, the group can be arranged $4!$ ways in $10$ positions, for a total of $240$ ways.
Italians: $3$ members, the group can be arranged $3!$ ways in $11$ positions, for a total of $66$ ways.
French: $6$ members, the group can be arranged $6!$ ways in $7$ positions for a total of $5040$ ways.

Adding these all up, and then dividing by the total number of permutations gives: $$\frac{(240 + 66 + 5040)}{6227020800}= \frac{1}{1164800}$$

My problem is that I am sure that I am double counting some of these sets, and I do not know how to fix that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you might be *undercounting* them. The $4! * 3! * 6!$ items you;ve got could be set in one-to-one correspondence with arrangments where Germans are on the left, Italians in the middle, and French on the right. But there are other arrangement beyond those, which you have not counted.

Comment: @John ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: In any "good" arrangement, there's an italian bloc, a german bloc, and a french bloc. How many ways are there to order these three blocs? Multiply that by the answer you got, and ...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the oversight already mentioned in the comments, the numbers of options for the national blocks should be multiplied, not added (see [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)).

So the probability is

$$
\frac{3!\cdot4!\cdot3!\cdot6!}{13!}=\frac1{10010}\approx10^{-4}\;.
$$